# Render a PDF with phantom and send it to the browser in node.js

Tags: node.js

How can i render a page and send the PDF to the browser?, this code it's fine to just generate the pdf on the server, using phantom = require('phantom') and express:

```
app.get('/report/:c', function(req, res) {
    phantom.create().then(function(ph) {
        ph.createPage().then(function(page) {
            page.property('paperSize', {
                format: 'Letter',
                orientation: 'portrait'
            });
            page.property('viewportSize', {
                width: 1056,
                height: 816
            });
            page.open("myUrl").then(function(status) {
                setTimeout(function() {
                    page.render('mypage.pdf').then(function() {
                        res.send('Page Rendered');
                        ph.exit();
                    });
                }, 2000);
            });
        });
    });
})
```

Anybody knows?

Answer (score 0):

You need something like this:

This will pipe your stream to `res`

```
router.get('/some_route', function(req, res, next) {


    phantom.create().then(function(ph) {
        ph.createPage().then(function(page) {

            var url = "somethingggg";

            page.open(url).then(function(status) {

                var file_name = path.join(__dirname, 'report.pdf');

                page.render(file_name).then(function() {

                    var from = fs.createReadStream(file_name);

                    from.pipe(res);
                    from.on('end', function() {
                        ph.exit();
                    });

                });
            });
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: i get this: Resource interpreted as Document but transferred with MIME type application/pdf, buti think is express error (Only in chrome) you know how to fix it? and as i can see the pdf stays in the server, theres a way to just send the pdf but without saving in the server?

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the content-Disposition for pdf `'Content-Disposition': 'attachment; filename=example.pdf'`. You can view this repo for further details [aProxy](https://github.com/akinjide/aproxy) and you are not sending back the rendered file.